# How Do I Send an HTTP POST Request via curl Using Groovy?

Tags: java, xml, curl, groovy, http-post

I have an application that needs to send a POST request to a third-party API. I'm stuck with a legacy version of java that doesn't support the required security ciphers, so I'm trying to send the request using groovy and curl as a workaround. The problem I'm running into is that I can't seem to find a way of formatting the data being posted that curl will accept. The request data is xml that includes spaces and special characters. Every approach I have tried so far results in a '400' error.

I have tried:

**no wrapping** - treats the first space as the end of the data

**wrapping with single or double quotes** - same as above

**replacing all spaces with %20** - 400 error

I'm out of ideas at this point. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

My Groovy code:

```
class UPSRequest {
    static main(args) {
    
            def request="""<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><AccessRequest xml:lang=\"en-US\"><UserId>foo</UserId><Password>abc@123</Password></AccessRequest><?xml version=\"1.0\"?><TrackRequest xml:lang=\"en-US\"><Request><TransactionReference><CustomerContext>My App</CustomerContext><XpciVersion>1.0001</XpciVersion></TransactionReference><RequestAction>Track</RequestAction><RequestOption>none</RequestOption></Request><ShipmentIdentificationNumber>1Z12345E1392654435</ShipmentIdentificationNumber></TrackRequest>""";
            def command = """curl https://wwwcie.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Track -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST -d ${request}""";
            def proc = command.execute();
            def outputStream = new StringBuffer();
            proc.waitForProcessOutput(System.out, System.err)
        }
}
```

Comment: Does the curl command work if you start it directly in the command line?

Comment: @vanje Yes. When I execute command on the command line, it correctly interprets the wrapping ' or " characters and passes along the data as a complete string. When I do the same thing from groovy it seems to be ignoring the wrapping quotes.

Comment: You can try to store the XML content to a file and use the `-d @filename` syntax to send the file content.

Comment: Maybe in conjunction with `--data-binary`.

Comment: Don't use `String.execute()` - instead use `List.execute()`